# how to get the event id from last created event in calendar in android studio?

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I inserted the events in android calander using this code

```
 for(int L=0; L < jsonArray.length(); L++)
            {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(L);
                    year[L] = jsonObject.getString("year");
                    month[L] = jsonObject.getString("month");
                    day[L] = jsonObject.getString("day");
                    StartTime[L] = jsonObject.getString("StartTime");
                    Endtime[L] = jsonObject.getString("Endtime");
                    Hours[L] = jsonObject.getString("Hours");
                    final ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
                    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
                    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "WORKING SCHEDULE OF THE WEEK");
                    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "selva");
                    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "chennai");

            eventID[L] = Long.parseLong(baseUri.getLastPathSegment());

                }//end of for for

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event Created"+eventID[1]   , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

using the for loop i inserted the event in diffrent date,but i need to get the event id of the created event.

so i saw a post in developrs.com, and i use this  line

```
eventID[L] = Long.parseLong(baseUri.getLastPathSegment());
```

to get the eventid,but when i try to run the app. i get closed.i dont know why,there is no error in code,but the app get closed, this statement is used to get the id of last created event from calander.

basically what i am doing here is using the for loop i insert the event in diffrent dates,and i try to get the event id each time when the for loop is executed,and store the id in array eventid[], and i try to display them in toast message.

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `eventId` of the previously created event, you just have to fetch it from the JSON response. A successful call to [events.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) returns an [event resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) which contains the `eventId`.